# Handling spaces in filenames when parsing with lex

Tags: c, lex

I am trying to make a parser with Lex that is able to read in filenames that may be more than one word without splitting them into tokens.

```
WORD    [a-zA-Z0-9\/\.-]+
SPECIAL [()><|&;*]

%%
    _argcount = 0; 
    _args[0] = NULL; 

{WORD}|{SPECIAL} {  
      if(_argcount < _numargs-1) {
        _args[_argcount++] = (char *)strdup(yytext);
        _args[_argcount] = NULL;
      }
    }
```

Currently it will split the string "Hello World.txt" (with the double quotes) into two words, Hello and World.txt (no quotes).

How do I make it so that any strings surrounded by quotes are not split up and the double quotes are not removed?

Comment: Add a quoting token and from there switch to an "inside quotes" state.

Comment: It's pretty likely that you really do want to remove the quotes, by the way. At least, if you are accumulating an `argv` array to pass to `execv`, you'll definitely want to strip the quotes.